# Any way of knowing if Firebase write has been added to the local queue?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When a user is offline and the user attempts to write to the Firebase Database, i want to show a message that the data is added to the local queue and will be shown when you are back online.
But neither the onSuccessListener or onFailureListener is called when the user is offline so is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onSuccessListener` and `onFailure` listener fire when the operation has been committed/rejected on the server.

For local operations you don't need a listener at all. When the `setValue()` operation completes, the write has been committed to the local queue - and when disk persistence is enabled to the local disk too.